# Change value with dropdown in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want your[image] suggestion If I change my dropdown select options then I want to change my table value for your better understand I am uploading a picture.Thanks

I am uploading my controller code

```
 public function index()
{
    $allRoom =AllocateClassroom::with('course','department')->paginate(10);

    //dd($allRoom);
    return view('Admin.allocateClassrooms.index',['allRoom'=>$allRoom]);

}
```

Here is my view code

```
 {{Form::label('department','Department')}}
            <select name="department" id="department" class="form-control">
                <option value=" ">----Select Department-----</option>
                @foreach($allRoom as $value)
                    <option value="{{$value->id}}">{{$value->department->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>

                    <br>
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                          <table class="table table-bordered">
                                  <tr class="success">
                                      <th>ID</th>
                                      <th>Course Code</th>
                                      <th>Course Name</th>
                                      <th>Schedule Info</th>
                                  </tr>

                                  <tr class="info" id="info">
                                      <td class="success" >{{$value->id}}</td>
                                      <td class="success" >{{$value->course->code}}</td>
                                      <td class="success" >{{$value->course->name}}</td>
                                      <td class="success" >{{$value->   Room_No}}
                                          {{$value->    date}}
                                          {{$value->    start_time}}
                                          {{$value->    end_time}}


                                      </td>
                                  </tr>
                          </table>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Please post your working code to know how to help you

Comment: I upload this above please you can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way i would do it:

First, i add a form wrapping the select so when a user changes its value the page reloads with the department selected

```
<form method="get" id="department-form">
    <select name="department" id="department" class="form-control" onchange="document.getElementById('department-form').submit()">
        <option value=" ">----Select Department-----</option>
        @foreach($allRoom as $value)
            <option value="{{$value->id}}" @if($value->id == $department) selected @endif>{{$value->department->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</form>
```

And in my controller i would have this:

```
public function index( Request $request)
{
    $department = null;
    if($request->department) $department = $request->department;
    $allRoom =AllocateClassroom::with('course','department')->whereHas('department', function($query) use($department){
        if($department) $query->where(id, $department);
    })->paginate(10);

    return view('Admin.allocateClassrooms.index',['allRoom'=>$allRoom, 'department' => $department]);

}
```

Here I get my department from the request and query the data with it

**Update**

Sorry, last code was getting all rooms and the departments that met the condition. Now it gets only the rooms that met the department condition

Comment: Everything is fine but I have faced this problem (2/2) ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: in the controller or the view? @KaziBablu

Comment: (2/2) ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object (View: F:\laragon\www\university\resources\views\Admin\allocateClassrooms\index.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get a property of a non-object. Change `{{$value->id}}` to `{{$value['id']}}` in the file that gives your error.